# mount boot camp partition

Tags: filesystem, data-recovery, partitioning, fdisk, bootcamp

I have my hard drive from my mac it has a boot camp patition, but the mac is dead.
Ubutnu sees the partition, calling it /dev/sdc3 and reporting that it has a basic linux data partition. I tried to mount it with `#mount /dev/sdc3 folder`. But it  told me I need to specify the partition type. 
ok. I went to `#fdisk -l | grep sdc`

and got

`/dev/sdc3   *       72850       72863      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS`

so then I tried:

```
# mount -t ntfs /dev/sdc3 folder
# mount -t hpfs /dev/sdc3 folder
```

both failed, telling me to look at dmesg | tail so heres that:
[ 3408.950969] HPFS: Bad magic ... probably not HPFS

and the fail for ntfs:

## mount -t ntfs /dev/sdc3 folder/

NTFS signature is missing.

sooo... what kind of partition is bootcamp? and how do I mount it?

Comment: did you check this thread? http://superuser.com/questions/84446/how-to-mount-a-hfs-partition-in-ubuntu-as-read-write

Comment: I did not see that thread. I do have hfsprogs, Im not particularly concerned with writing, but reading would be great. I didnt try hfsplus because fdisk didn't list it as such. but I'm certainly willing to try it when i get home. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple's Boot Camp uses a [hybrid MBR](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/hybrid.html) to help a BIOS-booted Windows coexist with an EFI-booted OS X. As noted on the linked-to page, hybrid MBRs are dangerous and trouble-prone. I suspect you may be running into a problem related to this. Your `fdisk` output seems to show the MBR side of things -- certainly the single line of output you've shown is consistent with either a pure MBR disk or a hybrid MBR, not with a pure GPT disk. (Hint: Don't be stingy with program output when posting questions; show the *entire* output of a command like `fdisk -l /dev/sdc`!)

One of the problems with hybrid MBRs is that the MBR and GPT sides can get out of sync. It's entirely possible that this has happened to you -- but that's speculative on my part. To know, you'd need to compare the start and end points of the GPT and MBR partition tables. To do this, run both `gdisk -l /dev/sdc` (to see the GPT side) and `fdisk -l /dev/sdc` (to see the MBR side), and compare the data.

Another possibility is that you're not accessing the correct partition. The MBR's `/dev/sdc3` (which you've identified as being a Windows partition) may not be the same as the GPT's `/dev/sdc3`. This is a critical point because in Linux, the GPT side is what's used to create device identifiers, so when you tried to mount `/dev/sdc3`, you were probably mounting the GPT's `/dev/sdc3`, not the MBR's `/dev/sdc3`. (Of course, this assumes that the disk has a hybrid MBR, which isn't certain given the information you've presented, although I think it's likely.) Again, comparing the GPT and MBR data from `gdisk` and `fdisk`, respectively, will help you understand what's going on.